# How to listen for Image/Video add (Content Observer) in A Background Service

Tags: android, service, contentobserver

I have created a Content Observer which listens for the add/change in the Media.Image Content. I need this content observer to register in the background service and need it to listen as long as the app is installed. It also needs to work when the app is closed.

ie, it is a long running observer which will end when the app uninstalls.
How can we do this?

Comment: if min api level is 24+ then use `JobInfo.Builder#addTriggerContentUri`, if not you have to use `ContentResolver#registerContentObserver`

Comment: @pskink current min is 16. ContentResolver#registerContentObserver where we need to write the code in activity or in service

Comment: do that in a service